# "Discards qualifiers" error with virtual function and/or const in c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constants

The more I research this problem, the more confused I seem to be getting.  This is a homework problem which involves augmenting code given us by our professor.  I know the problem has to do with the const keyword, and some very confusing new applications of it.

There is a generic class, Object, from which several subclasses (Sphere, Cone, Polygon) inherit.  Here are the classes in Object:

```
public: // computational members                                                
    // return t for closest intersection with ray                               
    virtual float intersect(const Ray &ray) const = 0;

    // return color for intersection at t along ray r                           
    virtual const Vec3 appearance(const World &w,
                                  const Ray &r, float t) const = 0;

    //The following function is added by me
    virtual const Vec3 normal(Vec3 p);
};
```

I added the final function, normal.

So within, for instance, the Sphere class, this is implemented thusly:

```
const Vec3 Sphere::normal(Vec3 p)
{
  return (p - d_center).normalize();
}
```

When I `make', I get the following error:

```
Appearance.cpp: In member function ‘const Vec3 Appearance::eval(const World&, const Vec3&, const Vec3&, Vec3, int) const’:
Appearance.cpp:46: error: passing ‘const Object’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘virtual const Vec3 Object::normal(Vec3)’ discards qualifiers
make: *** [Appearance.o] Error 1
```

Can you help me understand why this is happening?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't appear to have posted the code for `Appearance::eval`, which is what the error message is complaining about./

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the error-message refers to the `‘this’ argument` of a method, it means (a pointer to) the object that you're calling the method on. For example, in `shape->normal(v)`, `shape` is the `this` argument.

To specify that a given method doesn't modify its own object — its `this` argument — you need to *append* `const` to its declaration. So, change this:

```
virtual const Vec3 normal(Vec3 p);
```

to this:

```
virtual const Vec3 normal(Vec3 p) const;
```

to indicate that it's "safe" to call `normal(...)` on a `const` object.

Similarly, change this:

```
const Vec3 Sphere::normal(Vec3 p)
```

to this:

```
const Vec3 Sphere::normal(Vec3 p) const
```

Comment: I think I follow, although I'm no less confused by the syntax.  I made the changes you suggest, and this fixed the problem.  Thanks very much!

Comment: @FrankHarris: You're welcome! The syntax is slightly arbitrary; there needs to be some way to indicate that a given method is supposed to be "read-only", that is, that it should "safe" to call it on a `const` object, and therefore that its `this` pointer has type `const ... *` rather than just `... *`. Since the `this` pointer is implicit, there's no obvious place to provide its type-qualifiers, but after-the-parameter-list was apparently chosen as the place with the least opportunity for it to be misinterpreted as applying to something else.

Answer (score 1):

Like the compiler says, attempting to call a non-const function from a const function would lose the const-ness of the object itself.

You would have to make the `normal` function const as well, or avoid calling it.